# JQuery: looping through tables and counting the rows in each one

Tags: jquery, parsing, web-scraping, html-table

I'm trying to scrape tables from a Wikipedia page using jQuery. There are 51 relevant tables, and I'd like to count number of rows in each one. The tables didn't come with IDs, so I gave them some. Here's my code:

```
    const curl = require("/Users/ericknowles/node_modules/curl");
    const jsdom = require("/Users/ericknowles/node_modules/jsdom");

    const url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_of_Representatives_elections,_2016";
    curl.get(url, null, (err,resp,body)=>{
      if(resp.statusCode == 200){
         parseData(body);
      }
      else{
         //some error handling
         console.log("error while fetching url");
      }
    });

    function parseData(html){
        const {JSDOM} = jsdom;
        const dom = new JSDOM(html);
        const $ = (require('/Users/ericknowles/node_modules/jquery'))(dom.window);

        // extract all tables from the page
        var tables = $(".wikitable");

        // the relevant tables don't have IDs, so let's give them some
        for(var id = 4; id < 54; id++){
            $(tables[id]).attr('id', 'table_'+id);
        }

        for(var id = 4; id < 54; id++){
            currentTable = 'table_' + id;
            var rowCount = $('#' + currentTable 'tr').length;
            console.log(currentTable + " " + rowCount);
        }
    }
```

The final loop is giving me trouble. If there were only one table whose rows I needed to count, I'd use `var rowCounty = $('#myTable tr').length;`, but I need to loop through a list of tables with subscripts (`table_4, table_5, ... table_53`). I can't seem to get the syntax right. For instance, the code above gives me:

```
    var rowCount = $('#' + currentTable 'tr').length;
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

(I've tried lots of variations to no avail.) Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: *"The tables didn't come with IDs, so I gave them some. "* Why?

Answer (score 0):

DOM `HTMLTableElement` instances have a [`rows` property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-table-rows) which is a collection of the rows in the table.

No need for IDs. Just:

```
const tables = $(".wikitable");
const rowsPerTable = tables.map((_, table) => table.rows.length).get();
```

Live Example:

```js
const tables = $(".wikitable");
const rowsPerTable = tables.map((_, table) => table.rows.length).get();
console.log(rowsPerTable);
```

```css
.wikitable {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table class="wikitable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Just one row</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="wikitable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Two rows...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>...in this one</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="wikitable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Five</td></tr>
    <tr><td>rows</td></tr>
    <tr><td>in</td></tr>
    <tr><td>this</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That returns an array of numbers, where each number is the number of rows in the equivalent table in `tables`. Here's how it works:

- jQuery's [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) calls its callback with the index of the element and the element. We don't use the index (so I called it `_`) but we use the element.
- Within the callback, we use the `rows` property.
- Since jQuery's `map` returns a jQuery object, we use [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the raw array.

Or if you want to combine your table IDs starting with 4 and the row counts, perhaps as objects:

```
const tables = $(".wikitable");
const rowsPerTable = tables.map((index, table) => ({id: index + 4, count: table.rows.length})).get();
```

Live Example:

```js
const tables = $(".wikitable");
const rowsPerTable = tables.map((index, table) => ({id: index + 4, count: table.rows.length})).get();
console.log(rowsPerTable);
```

```css
.wikitable {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table class="wikitable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Just one row</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="wikitable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Two rows...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>...in this one</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="wikitable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Five</td></tr>
    <tr><td>rows</td></tr>
    <tr><td>in</td></tr>
    <tr><td>this</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Some people don't like to rely on that property, although it's universally supported and part of the standard. If you don't, you can use `querySelectorAll` on the table instead:

```
const tables = $(".wikitable");
const rowsPerTable = tables.map((_, table) => table.querySelectorAll("tr").length).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try `var rowCount = $('#' + currentTable + ' tr').length;`

This is for the error I don't know for the result.